# Uncaught TypeError: playlist.querySelector is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener

I'm trying to change the main video on the page to another video when a user clicks on one of the thumbnail img links.

Essentially this code is supposed to:

- grab each video playlist (if there are 1 or more)
- grab each playlists video tag and source tag
- loop through all the video links
- add a click listener to each link which grabs the added data-video-src attribute that I added, and apply it to the video source,
- load the video.

Here is the HTML:
[This is the HTML code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUQ3B.png)

Below is the JavaScript but when I run it I get:

> "Uncaught TypeError: playlist.querySelector is not a function"

What am I doing wrong?:

[ChangeVideo.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUQ3B.png)

Comment: please upload your code in https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: posting code images are not appreciated by us. please upload your code here not the image

Comment: Add the relevant script in the question itself (preferable as a running snippet) and only use an external source like jsfiddle/jsbin as a last resort. After that, read on how a [`for...in...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loops work and [why using it for arrays (or array like collections) is a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-a-bad-idea)

Comment: Here is a link to my project on jsfiddle.net

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/user/dashboard/fiddles/

Comment: Please add the relevant script **in the question itself** (preferable as a running snippet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing 
`for(playlist in document.querySelectorAll('.video-playlist'))` which will set the value of `playlist` with the value of key of `document.querySelectorAll('.video-playlist')`. And since `document.querySelectorAll('.video-playlist')` is a array type the key will be `0`, `1` , `2`, and so on. So, `playlist` will have numeric value `0`, `1` , `2`, ... With this `playlist.querySelector` will give you that error

> "Uncaught TypeError: playlist.querySelector is not a function"

To overcome this you need to select each element of `document.querySelectorAll('.video-playlist')` rather than its `index`. For that you need to change the `for` loop to use `of` instead of `in` like

```
for(playlist of document.querySelectorAll('.video-playlist'))
```

When you use `of` in the `for` loop then it will assign each element of `document.querySelectorAll('.video-playlist')` to `playlist`. And when you get the element in `playlist`, the function `querySelector` will be valid.

Comment: Well that did get rid of the "Uncaught TypeError: playlist.querySelector is not a function" error in Google DevTools but I can't get my code to work for some reason :(

Comment: @Christoph now that is something different concern that what this question demands. You should be happy that your issue is resolved for at least what you asked in this question. Don't get upset. Try debugging your code.

Comment: addEventListener is not working when I click on my links. Not sure what the problem is. I'm trying to debug it now.

Comment: @Christoph if it does not work, you can create a new question with relevant HTML and JavaScript there. I am glad to help you in this question.

Comment: @Christoph you can tick mark the answer to depict that this solved what has been asked in the question.

Comment: Thanks this answers my question.

Comment: @Christoph glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

the problem is because for playlist in ... with have playlist as the index of the array.

try this

```
var playlists = document.querySelectorAll('.video-playlist');
for (var i = 0; i < playlists.length; i++) {
  var playlist = playlists[i];
  ...
});
```

and also the internal for in loop needs to change too.

thanks

Comment: I've removed my comment because of the `for...of...` solution. But to answer your question. No, it won't work in any IE. You have to look for [`NodeList.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach#Browser_Compatibility) (because that's what `querySelectorAll()` returns). Your caniuse link shows the info for `Array.prototype.forEach()`